# Transparently executing SQL functions when loading/saving a field in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I'm working with Doctrine2, and have a entity containing a string property that represents a [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) geometry:

```
class Entity {
    /** @Column(type="string") */
    protected $wkt;
}
```

I'd like to have this field transparently saved to a [GEOMETRY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/geometry-property-functions.html) field in the database, as such:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES(GeomFromText(?))
SELECT AsText(field) FROM ...
```

I had a look at the [custom mapping types](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/basic-mapping.html#custom-mapping-types), but couldn't find where to apply such an SQL function.

Any idea?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're hoping to update a field in the database whenever another field is modified? I'm not too familiar with Doctrine, but you could probably use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html).

Comment: No, actually I just need a transparent transformation between WKT (text) and Geometry (binary) when persisting/hydrating an entity! The database handles that with the GeomFromText() and AsText() SQL functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that this feature is not currently implemented, but a feature request does exist for it:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-15

It might be available in Doctrine 2.2

**Update**: this feature has been confirmed for 2.2, which is to be release [soon](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL/fixforversion/10142).

**Update**: this is now available in Doctrine 2.2!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look at [LifecycleCallbacks](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-haslifecyclecallbacks):

```
/**
 * @PrePersist
 */
public function sendOptinMail() {
    //do sql query : SELECT GeoFromText()...
    $this->yourField = ...
}
```

and then set the field to the returned value.

Comment: That would mean injecting the db in my model, something I want to avoid... and does not give a solution for retrieving the value!